# linking static library instead of dynamic

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have a directory named FOO which has X.a and X.so . I want to choose only X.a.
So in my makefile I am using the following to link it

```
EXE: OBJ.o
     g++ -L/PATH/TO/FOO -o $@ $< -static -lX
```

But when I do that, I get the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
```

How should this be done properly. One way is to give abs path of X.a. Is there some other way?

Comment: The linker does not have a problem finding X.a, it complains about other libs. I think you should add the path to these, too (with -L).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
EXE: OBJ.o
     g++ -L/PATH/TO/FOO -o $@ $< -Wl,-Bstatic -lX -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

Comment: Thanks Jack...It worked ... Could you explain the meaning of `-Wl,-Bstatic -lX -Wl,-Bdynamic` ?

Comment: `-Wl,-Bstatic`: `-Wl` means that the flag needs to be sent to the linker and `-Bstatic` turns on static linking. `-lX` is the normal flag to link in `libX`. `-Wl,-Bdynamic` sends the `-Bdynamic` flag to the linker, dynamically linking all the other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the documentation for `ld` correctly, you don't have to specify the absolute path, but you can specify a library using its full name as such:

```
EXE: OBJ.o
     g++ -L/PATH/TO/FOO -o $@ $< -l:X.a
```

Comment: At least this means the linker is now trying to link against the static library, like you want; unfortunately it cannot find it. Are you sure the path given to the -L switch is correct?

Comment: You have to specify the full name of the library, so it should be `-l:libX.a`